# React Native Navigation Fatal Exception: Tried to create view after it has already been destroyed

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

**Issue Description::**

I am working on React native application and using React Native Navigation for routing, [GitHub link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

Sometimes my app crash on Android as I have crashlytics installed So I verified crashes using Firebase crash logs. I am getting this error log inside crashlytics::

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried to create view
>   after it has already been destroyed
>          at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.ViewController.getView(ViewController.java:161)
>          at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.ParentController.getView(ParentController.java:60)
>          at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.StackController.lambda$push$4(StackController.java:172)
>          at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.-$$Lambda$StackController$06hFigyLWXXMellTVVP0d0y7blk.run(Unknown
>   Source:8)
>          at com.reactnativenavigation.anim.NavigationAnimator$1.onAnimationEnd(NavigationAnimator.java:64)
>          at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>          at android.animation.AnimatorSet.endAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1294)
>          at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1079)
>          at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
>          at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
>          at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1170)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:984)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:806)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1158)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

This is only happening inside Android application. I am not able to reproduce this case again, sometimes it occurs automatically. Most of the time it occurs when child screen is comes over the parent screen.

Code::

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
                component: {
                    id: screenId,
                    name: screenName,
                    passProps: props,
                    options: options
                }
            });

Navigation.popToRoot(this.props.componentId);
```

I am using ::

- react native version :: 0.58.6
- react native navigation :: 2.12.0

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code you can check now.

Comment: Do you need both the `popToRoot` calls?

Comment: No, I just need following once.

Comment: Are you sure `popToRoot` is related? The line where the error originates (StackController line 172) isn't reached when calling popToRoot

Comment: We are only use navigation functions is `push`, `popToRoot` and `pop` only.

Comment: Please describe the structure of the root layout when the crash occurred.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora could you fix this exception? if yes, please share your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Maverick update your react-native and wix react native navigation versions.

Comment: Thanks @HarleenKaurArora RNN version is already latest. Will try updating RN version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is resolved in `2.13.1-snapshot.234` by [#47b7d2c](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/commit/47b7d2c7c54af861e99b922aa258489d86c9c0b2)